# What to do with “Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected”?

Tags: haskell, types, numerical, fad

I need the Numeric.FAD library, albeit still being completely puzzled by existential types.

This is the code:

```
error_diffs :: [Double] -> NetworkState [(Int, Int, Double)]
error_diffs desired_outputs = do diff_error <- (diff_op $ error' $ map FAD.lift desired_outputs)::(NetworkState ([FAD.Dual tag Double] -> FAD.Dual tag Double))
                                 weights <- link_weights
                                 let diffs = FAD.grad (diff_error::([FAD.Dual tag a] -> FAD.Dual tag b)) weights

                                 links <- link_list
                                 return $ zipWith (\link diff ->
                                                       (linkFrom link, linkTo link, diff)
                                                  ) links diffs
```

error' runs in a Reader monad, ran by diff_op, which in turn generates an anonymous function to take the current NetworkState and the differential inputs from FAD.grad and stuffs them into the Reader.

Haskell confuses me with the following:

```
Inferred type is less polymorphic than expected
  Quantified type variable `tag' is mentioned in the environment:
    diff_error :: [FAD.Dual tag Double] -> FAD.Dual tag Double
      (bound at Operations.hs:100:33)
In the first argument of `FAD.grad', namely
    `(diff_error :: [FAD.Dual tag a] -> FAD.Dual tag b)'
In the expression:
    FAD.grad (diff_error :: [FAD.Dual tag a] -> FAD.Dual tag b) weights
In the definition of `diffs':
    diffs = FAD.grad
              (diff_error :: [FAD.Dual tag a] -> FAD.Dual tag b) weights
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I write,

```
bigNumber :: (Num a) => a
bigNumber = product [1..100]
```

then when `bigNumber :: Int` is evaluated,
it's evaluating `(product :: [Int] -> Int) [(1 :: Int) .. (100 :: Int)]`,

and when `bigNumber :: Integer` is evaluated,
it's evaluating `(product :: [Integer] -> Integer) [(1 :: Integer) .. (100 :: Integer)]`.

Nothing is shared between the two.

`error_diffs` has a single type, that is: `[Double] -> NetworkState [(Int, Int, Double)]`.  It must evaluate in exactly one way.

However, what you have inside:

```
... :: NetworkState ([FAD.Dual tag Double] -> FAD.Dual tag Double)
```

can be evaluated in different ways, depending on what `tag` is.

See the problem?

Comment: No, sorry. I have no idea what purpose the tag type variable has. How am I supposed to deal with Numeric.FAD? All I need is derivation.

Comment: See http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.cafe/22308/ for a discussion of the "tagging" used by FAD.  I don't have Numeric.FAD installed, so I can't confidently help you with restructuring your code quite yet.  Maybe you can give it a try yourself, with hints from that article?

Answer (score 4):

this code gives the same error as you get:

```
test :: Int
test =
  (res :: Num a => a)
  where
    res = 5
```

The compiler figured that `res` is always of type `Int` and is bothered that for some reason you think `res` is polymorphic.

this code, however, works fine:

```
test :: Int
test =
  res
  where
    res :: Num a => a
    res = 5
```

here too, `res` is defined as polymorphic but only ever used as `Int`. the compiler is only bothered when you type nested expressions this way. in this case `res` could be reused and maybe one of those uses will not use it as `Int`, in contrast to when you type a nested expression, which cannot be reused by itself.